# How to rename sheets in a workbook with exceptions?

Tags: excel, vba

I intend to rename all the sheets with the cell "G2" value except the two sheets called "Main" and "Fixed".

The code keeps renaming the two sheets.

```
Sub RenameSheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    'With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    If ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name <> "Main" Or _
      ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name <> "Fixed" Then

        ws.Activate
        If Range("G2").Value = "" Then
            ActiveSheet.Name = Range("G2").End(xlDown).Value
        Else: ActiveSheet.Name = Range("G2").Value
        End If

    Else:
        GoTo Nextsv

End If

Nextsv:     Next ws

Sheets("Main").Activate
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code had 3 mistakes

1. You were using `Activate` and `Active` which produced the second error. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) on how to avoid these.
2. You were checking the name of the `ActiveSheet` before the `ws.Activate` so it would always check the previous sheet.
3. Your conditions were with `Or`. `Main` <> `Fixed` so it would change their name anyways because `Main` is not `Fixed` and mets the second part of your `Or` and viceversa. Use `And` to force the code check that both conditions are met.

This is the code without using `Activate` or `Select`:

```
Option Explicit
Sub RenameSheets()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Main" And ws.Name <> "Fixed" Then
            With ws
                If .Range("G2") = vbNullString Then
                    .Name = .Range("G2").End(xlDown)
                Else
                    .Name = .Range("G2")
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Damian, your code gives me a compile error "End if without Block IF"

Comment: @Yusuf yeah, noticed and fixed it a minute ago. Try the new code on my answer.

Comment: There's another issue, the code is attempting to rename all the sheets using the "G2" value from the Activesheet . can you see this?

Comment: @Yusuf You are right, sorry. Missed the `.` in front of `Range("G2")` for the  `Else` just add the dot there like in my answer and it will work fine.

Comment: Its fixed by declaring the sheetname :
                    .Name = ws.Range("G2").End(xlDown)
                Else
                    .Name = ws.Range("G2")

Comment: @Yusuf you don't need the whole reference, just the `.` in front of the range because it's withing a `With` block which means everything followed by the `.` will reference the `ws`. If my answer helped, please consider marking it as correct to close it.